# create a general purpose API class and fill in urls in Python

Tags: python, oop

So I am creating an API class in python, the goal of which is to allow me to create custom API routes that I can call methods on to make calls to APIs (as well as other helpful operations). However, I want this to be very general purpose and safe, as some of the API calls look a little different than others. What I want to know is, what is the best way to fill in an API call to a URL as a string using an OO approach? Take the following example:

```py
#
# ...defined apiObject class up here somewhere (name tbd)...
#

myAPI = apiObject('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/{}/{}') 
# Note the {} as placeholders for the API calls
# Below is an example of calling the API
myAPI.callAPI('comments', '123')
# This would form the url 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments/123' make the call and do some stuff

# Similarly:
myAPI2 = apiObject('https://anotherrestapi.test.com/{}/{}/{}')
myAPI.callAPI('2020', 'Feb', '13')
# Again, would form the url 'https://anotherrestapi.test.com/2020/Feb/13' make the call and do some stuff
```

This is not a problem I can't fix, moreover, its a question about best programming practices in Python. My initial reaction is to use `**kwargs` in the `callAPI` function as I could then name the placeholders and fill in the url as needed.

Alternatively, is there a way I should form my API class such that this is more set in stone?

Or last of all, do you have any library recommendations for me to check out as an alternative to doing this myself?

---

I am not as familiar with Python as I am with other languages, so I thought I'd ask and see what other people think. Thanks in advance for taking the time to think about it.

Comment: If you’re writing a *server* i’d look at  https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/

Comment: @JLPeyret A friend introduced me to flask, so that's what I've been using. Do you know the differences between the two? Personally, I'm not too concerned with ultimate speed, but am looking for features with reasonable security.

Comment: well if it's API-oriented, and especially non-html, fastapi gets a lot of good press.  I use django myself, so I can't speak as to specifics.  however, you could do worse than just doing a quick tutorial on fastapi to get a feel for how the api mechanism is designed, at least from the user perspective.  you can also look at https://amitness.com/2020/06/fastapi-vs-flask/